# changing two variables at the same time with different results

Tags: php, mysql

$Energy = 100
$Stats = 50
It takes 5 energy to train and increase $Stats
100/5=20
If `<input>` has 20 and `<button>` is clicked
20 energy is multiplied by a number 
(corresponding with their level) lets say .291 for level 1
20*.291=5.82
What I would like to do then is add this number to $stats
50+5.82=55.82
In the end it should be
$Energy = 0
$Stats = 55.82

I have the `<form>` already set up. I just don't know how to update the two numbers at the same time. They are both on the same table in the same database.

I hope this is clear enough

Comment: Any reason 2 update querys can't be done?

Comment: And here you'll learn what transactions are.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. Are you looking to do the calculations in the database, or do the calculations in PHP and just update with the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php

```
$Energy = 100;
$Stats = 50;

$Points = 5;

$EnergyRatio = $Energy/$Points

$Level = 0.291;

$Stats += $EnergyRatio*$Level;

$Energy = 0;
```

Mysql

```
UPDATE Table SET energy=$Energy, stats=$Stats WHERE id=$Something
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you. I knew it was an UPDATE, but did not not how to put it together. Thank you.